# MongoDb update method not work properly

Tags: c#, mongodb

I use mongoDB in my project,and I use Collection.Update method in my code,but it not work properly, it will fail at sometimes,the code is pasted below:

```
collections.Update(Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(databaseid)),Update.Set("agent",ip))
```

If I tried to add code after this line maybe it will work at most of time：

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

so where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using legacy MongoDB driver. Current version of driver is 2.0.1 and it has [new async API](http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/update/). So you can await database operations without thread sleeping and guessing how long it will take. Assume you have some class with properties `Id` of type `ObjectId` and `Agent` of type `string`:

```
private async Task DoSomething(ObjectId id, string ip)
{
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var db = client.GetDatabase("databaseName");
    var collection = db.GetCollection<YourClass>("collectionName");
    var update = Builders<YourClass>.Update.Set(x => x.Agent, ip);
    var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(x => x.Id == id, update);
    // you can check update result here
}
```

So, just update your driver and use new async API.